# Write to spawned process stdin nodejs?

Tags: node.js, stream, stdin, child-process

I have a script that I want to run from another one. The problem is that the child script (process) needs an user input before it continues.

```
var child = spawn('script');
child.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString().trim()); // tells me to input my data
    child.stdin.write('my data\n');
});
```

After I input my data the child script should continue but instead it hang in there.

## Solution

Actually the above code work for me. I'm using [commander.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/commander.js) in the child script to prompt the user for action. Here is how I respond to a child's script prompt:

```
child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    switch (data.toString().trim()) {
        case 'Username:':
            child.stdin.write('user');
            break;
        case 'Password:':
            child.stdin.write('pass');
            break;
    }
});
```

Same thing work with [suppose](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-suppose):

```
var suppose = require('suppose');

suppose('script')
    .on('Username: ').respond('user')
    .on('Password: ').respond('pass')
.error(function (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
})
.end(function (code) {
    console.log(code);
    done();
});
```

Comment: Just a thought: do you need to end `stdin` in order for your script to respond?  See also: http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_end

Comment: From the docs: Closing this stream via end() often causes the child process to terminate. - http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdin
And it does terminate the child process I can confirm it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the package `suppose`. It's like [Unix Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect). Full disclosure, I'm the author.

From the example on the Github page, you can see an example of it scripting NPM: https://github.com/jprichardson/node-suppose

Example:

```
var suppose = require('suppose')
suppose('script')
.on(/\w*/).respond('my data\n')
.end(function(code){
  console.log('Done: ' + code); 
})
```

Comment: There seems to be some problem with my child script because it doesn't work with *suppose* either. I'm using *commander.js* in my child script to prompt the user for action. Maybe this is the problem in some way ..

Comment: I was missing one trailing white space character in the first prompt but I guess this is something specific to *commander.js*. Anyway your module work for me so I'll mark your answer.