# node.js child_process password input for git clone in atom

Tags: node.js, git, atom-editor, spawn

I am trying to clone a git repository requiring the child_process module of node.js in my atom package:

```
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var gitClone = spawn('git', ['clone', 'ssh://user@gitrepo.com/path/to/reponame'], {cwd: path});

    gitClone.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        gitClone.stdin.write('password');
        console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    });

    gitClone.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);

    });

    gitClone.on('close', (code) => {
        console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    });
```

As it is not possible to use a ssh key, I need to pass the user's password to the spawned process.

I thought regarding [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655713/write-to-spawned-process-stdin-nodejs) would solve my problem as well, but it seems like there is not a possibility to get into my `gitClone.stdout.on('data', function (data) { ... }`.
Any `console.log()` I am trying to perform from in there, will not be displayed on the chrome engine's console.

Here is my output:

```
    stderr: Cloning into 'reponame'...
    stderr: Permission denied, please try again.
    stderr: Permission denied, please try again.
    stderr: Permission denied (publickey,password).
    stderr: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
    child process exited with code 128
```

I am wondering why I can see only the sdterr-messages. When I run `git clone` in my bash it first tells me `Cloning into 'reponame'...`, then it asks for my password.

Is there a way to catch the password prompt in child_process' `spawn()`?